# Can't access from domain locally

Tags: dns, 18.04, telnet

I have a Nextcloud Server on my Ubuntu 18.04 system with ddclient installed. I can access my server from my domain on a different device on the same network but can't access my server from my domain on my computer. I always get a timeout error.

I've tried flushing my cache, ping & traceroute show my public ip address but telnet returns a timeout as well. I haven't modified my host file or dns. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I edited my `/etc/hosts` file to set the local IP address of the server to the domain locally.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add more detail.